# Intergrating Google plus local with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

I'm currently working on a site which provides information about local hotels and  resturents.We have decide to integrate a external system which provide rating and comments.We though Google plus local is a good one to integrate

Ex : https://plus.google.com/112054268577917984776/about?hl=en

The issue was we could not find a widget for  WP which provide a UI as the above link.
Appreciate if some one could explain the better approaches to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check Google Plus Apis section for this as they are still limited (really dont know if any plugin available for this feature or not)

Good link to follow, I think need to create plugin for that on your own or customize somewhat similar to your requirement [Places](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

You can also check their [Business Map APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/) if its fit in your requirement.